# Different time periods for different civilization

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

> During **`their`** Classic period, Mayan Civilization produced monumental
>   structures inscribed with intricate hieroglyphic texts that
>   archaeologists are beginning to decipher.

Why is the use of 'their' wrong here? Maybe the Mayan's had a different time scale then us, so won't using 'the' be incorrect? How can we correct the sentence and what is the error in its present form?

Answer (score 4):

Okay I think it is because '*their*' is **plural** while 'Mayan Civilisation' is singular. Maybe replacing it with '**its**' will be fine.